# Can not install any linux distros

Tags: windows, usb-drive, iso, burning

I can not install any linux distros on my old pc despite having easily install 2 times on my Win 10 PC. I am using Win XP 32 bit 2.82GHz Dual Core CPU, 1.99GB RAM. I have tried many instructions, watching countless videos, reading answers from forums for a month and still doesn't work it keeps going from problem to problem: rufus and etcher doesnt support, burn device not found on CDBurner XP, I also use Linux Live USB Creator but after a while it seems to work just like instructed and then nothing happen :(( I dont know what to do. Plan to throw my computer :<
Btw, sorry for my English

Comment: It could be that it isn't possible to install any of the distributions that you've tried on the hardware that you are using. It can range from attempting to install a 64 bit OS on a 32 bit processor to the specific hardware not being supported by the operating systems. If you've done all of the research that you can and it still isn't working, then it may be that it just can't be done.

Comment: try ubuntu; Alpine Linux, debian.

Answer (score 0):

May be because your processor is 32-bit. Not many distro support 32-bit. Debian and some other does. Burn a USB in some other computer and try booting.